# Gear icons for changing badge/privilege tracking in the Activity page vanished

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

Usually, little gear icons appear in the Activity page by the "next privilege" and "next badge" trackers. The gears have disappeared, but they work if I click on where they should be:

[image: the Reputation section, without gears]

I am signed in, and everything works normally if I click the right spot.

I'm using Chrome 49.0.2623.112 on 64-bit Windows 8.1.

Comment: It's also missing for me, latest Chrome and Firefox on 64-bit Windows 10. Consoles show no errors.

Comment: Looks like all sorts of icons have disappeared. The one for helpful flags... location... but I think it's limited to the profile page.

Comment: Where have all the icons gone?... We sure miss them!

Comment: I call it a minimalist design and tag this status-bydesign...

Comment: @rene Some minimalist design is **too** minimalist... Knowing where to hover/click isn't enough, I think :P

Comment: @Catija: The Answer, my friend, is blowing in the wind....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed this as well. When I investigated the issue, I discovered it was a bad SVG file merge. This has been fixed.

[image]